# System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions vs System.Web.WebPages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a mvc4 project armed with the knowledge of mvc3. On my razor view page, I have some html element such as: `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditClubDate", new { id=item.ID })`.

But I also found that in the namespace of `System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions` there is also a method call `ActionLink`. Does anyone know the difference?

Morover, I am getting errors in my error list on VS2012 that is written as

> System.Web.WebPages.HTml.HtmlHelper dose not contain a definition for
>   'ActionLink'

I have tried to modify my web.config file in both views folder and the top level folder.

Answer (score 0):

The same error i got and tried the below steps and it worked

1)Close Visual Studio

2)Delete bin and obj folders

3)Reopen your solution and rebuild

$)No more errors on the view

NOTE: No need to change anything on configuration files and a simple clean and rebuild solution does not work.

Comment: I fixed the second problem by changing <appSettings><add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" /><appSettings /> from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 and doing the steps: clean project => unload project =>reload project. Thanks.